# @JsonTypeName not working and return Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm learn about spring boot, however i stopped with this problem. I Have an person abstract class with @JsonSubTypes,a Client and Seller class what extends Person with @JsonTypeName. All requests return the error: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype.

Person class

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Client.class, name = "client"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Seller.class, name = "seller")
//    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Provider.class, name = "provider"),
})
public abstract class Person implements Comparable<Person>{
    @Id
    @Field("_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private String code;
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String email;
    @Field("created_at")
    private DateTime registerDate;

    public Person(String name, String phone, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
    }
```

Client class

```
@Document("clients")
@JsonTypeName("client")
public class Client extends Person{
    @Indexed(unique=true)
    private String cpf;
    @Field("credit_limit")
    private Double creditLimit;

    public Client(String name, String phone, String email, String cpf,
            Double creditLimit) {
        super(name, phone, email);
        this.cpf = cpf;
        this.creditLimit = creditLimit;
    }
```

Seller class

```
@Document("sellers")
@JsonTypeName("seller")
public class Seller extends Person {
    @Indexed(unique=true)
    private String cpf;
    @Field("monthly_goal")
    private Double monthlyGoal;

    public Seller(String name, String phone, String email, String cpf,
            Double monthlyGoal) {
        super(name, phone, email);
        this.cpf = cpf;
        this.monthlyGoal = monthlyGoal;
    }
```

Initial method

```
@PostMapping("sale/store")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> store(@RequestBody Client client) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("ok");
    }
```

Comment: post the error you are getting

Comment: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.bruno.boticario.model.Client]: missing type id property '@type'; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class com.bruno.boticario.model.Client]: missing type id property '@type

Comment: Do you pass `"type": "client"` field in the request JSON?

Comment: No, even with @JsonTypeName in Client class it is necessary send type in the request?

Comment: Of course :)  Otherwise Jackson won't be able to deserialize and map properly to the child class.

Comment: This method is necessary 4 params. 
```
public ResponseEntity<String> store(@RequestBody Client client, @RequestBody Seller seller, @RequestBody Integer paymentMethod,
   @RequestBody ArrayList<SaleItem> saleItemList) {
//  Sale sale = new Sale(client, seller, saleItemList, paymentMethod);
//  repository.save(sale);
  return ResponseEntity.ok("ok");
 }
```
As would be the request?

Comment: No, in such case you need to handle one `Sale` object passed in the request: `public ResponseEntity<String> store(@RequestBody Sale sale) {}` as multiple request bodies [should not be handled](stackoverflow.com/questions/12893566/passing-multiple-variables-in-requestbody-to-a-spring-mvc-controller-using-ajax)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're missing to submit `"type":"client"` field in the JSON request body.
But you'll also need to provide default constructors in `Person`, `Client`, `Seller` classes or mark available constructors with `@JsonCreator` annotation:

```
// Client with explicit creator
    @JsonCreator
    public Client(
            @JsonProperty("name") String name, 
            @JsonProperty("phone") String phone, 
            @JsonProperty("email") String email, 
            @JsonProperty("cpf") String cpf,
            @JsonProperty("creditLimit") Double creditLimit) {
        super(name, phone, email);
        this.cpf = cpf;
        this.creditLimit = creditLimit;
    }
// ------
// seller: use default constructor (also to be added in `Person`) for Jackson
public Seller() {}

// person
public Person() {}
```